# Symfony FormBuilder create multidimensional field name

Tags: symfony, formbuilder

It is possible to use the basic types of field to create a multidimensional array name?
For example:

```
<input type="text" name="my_type[translations][name][de]">
<input type="text" name="my_type[translations][name][fr]">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ColectionType](http://symfony.com/doc/2.7/reference/forms/types/collection.html). But then you will probably need to change something about how you're using input names like here `name="my_type[translations][name][fr]"`, maybe `name="my_type[translations][nameFr]"`. Using it, your inputs will look like

```
<input type="text" name="my_type[translations][0][nameDe]">
<input type="text" name="my_type[translations][0][nameFr]">

<input type="text" name="my_type[translations][1][nameDe]">
<input type="text" name="my_type[translations][1][nameFr]">
```

Here I also presume that you have `Translation` entity which would have `nameDe` and `nameFr` properties.